# MySites giving a Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage as the central admin server name has been added incorrectly

Tags: my-site, central-administration

Currently I have a front end web server. When I hit http://frontendserver1:3000 I get the Stay Connected page appear.

[image: Stay Connected My Site SharePoint 2010]

Clicking on My Profile (in the image) works fine. Clicking on My Colleagues returns:

> Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

[image: Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage]

Looking at the URL of the site is has change to http://centaladminserver:3000/_layouts/MyContactLinks.aspx

centaladminserver is the wrong machine name. It should be centaladminserver1. Where would I change the settings to make the front end servers use that machine name?

Comment: The writing of this question helped me solve my issue.

Comment: You might want to try and search for the issue first, I know I've answered the question more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to:

> Central Admin > Application Management > Manage service applications >
>   User Profile Service Application  > Setup My Sites

Then edit My Site Host and select OK